# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, numpy, error-messaging

```
import numpy as np
import math

y = 0.
m = 9.
A = 0.3
k = 4.
gamma = 0.15
t = 0

n = 101

t_array = np.zeros(n)
y_array = np.zeros(n)
dt = 25/n
for i in range(n):
    t_array[i] = 0 + dt * i
    y_array[i] = A * math.exp(-gamma * t) * math.cos * (math.sqrt(k/m) * t)
    print("%5.2f %5.2f" % (y_array[i], t_array[i]))
```

I cannot for the love of my life figure out why I get the message: "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'". I've looked at pretty much all the suggestions on this website. Please help!

Comment: `* math.cos` ??

Comment: `math.cos` is a function. You can't use it as if it were an integer. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `math.cos?` Its a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.cos` is a function, in particular it's a `builtin_function_or_method` - which explains the error message.

That means you have to call it with an argument to get a number, just like you did with `math.exp` and `math.sqrt`.